# eBPF / XDP fails to compile on Ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: ubuntu, ebpf

After upgrading Ubuntu 16.04, it's no longer possible to compile eBPF. The `bpf.h` file is missing key structs and the `uapi` headers don't seem to be installed.

Sample code:

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>

int main()
{
    return XDP_DROP;
}
```

Compiled with `clang -target bpf -O2 -c xdp.c -o xdp.o`

This returns the error:

```
udp.c:13:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'XDP_DROP'
    return XDP_DROP;
           ^
1 error generated.
```

```
$ cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
$ uname -r
4.4.0-148-generic
```

No mention of XDP

```
$ grep -r XDP_DROP /usr/include
$ grep -r XDP_DROP /lib/modules/
$
```

What's the issue?

Comment: What do `grep -r XDP_DROP /usr/include`, `apt search xdp` and `apt search bpf` say?

Comment: Please put the outputs in the question so we can read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your kernel is 4.4.0-148, this is too old to have XDP support. XDP was introduced in Linux **4.8** (see [this document](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/kernel-versions.md)).

Not sure what system you upgraded from. Try upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 if you can? Or try installing a newer kernel (and relevant headers).